# Pre-creating Cardano Wallet Receiving Addresses for later use

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

Does it matter when a receiving address is used to receive ADA into a wallet?
For example:

- I use cardano-node/cardano-wallet to create a wallet.
- I then generate 100 receiving addresses for that wallet.
- I store the receiving addresses in a database table
- Over time, as needed, I use one of the receiving addresses to allow a user of a service to send ADA to the wallet, I mark that address as "Used=1" in the table, and use the next unused address the next time one is needed for that same customer, or a different customer.
- At some point, if unused addresses are getting low, I get a notification - and proceed to generate more receiving addresses and add them to the table to replenish the pool of unused addresses.

There are some benefits to doing this in this way...do you see problems with this methodology? Is it not feasible because of a time-based limitation on using a receiving address generated for a wallet or some other such issue I am not aware of?

Does this seem like a reasonable strategy at least until I have a more dynamic/on-demand wallet address generating system devised/implemented?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems in doing it this way. Just make sure you save the recovery words in safe places, to be able to recover the wallet.
You can also take a look at my script here to see the way I'm using to manage some of my wallets:
https://gist.github.com/cardano-apexpool/99784308812bdf7aa01446fa95f47fd2

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at my question and responding!
Thanks too for the link to your repo.  
- @data_relevant